# How to print JSON from .getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am totally new to jQuery and AJAX and I am having trouble viewing an AJAX call that I am making. The JSON response shows up in the browser when I make the call by typing it into the address bar but I'm having trouble viewing it using something like an alert. Is there a way to view everything that is coming back like some sort of print line command that I can use?

I've been able to get this example to work

```
       var url = "https://graph.facebook.com/zombies";
       $(document).ready(function(){
          $.getJSON(url, function(results){              
               //alert("got here");               
               alert(results.about);
              });
          });
```

The JSON file I am trying to return has file has many nested arrays and won't return anything into my alert box. (or I dont know how to make it return anything ) Thanks ahead of time for any help anyone can lend!!

Comment: Does console show any errors? Also check if the response is in json encoded format. Also try `console.log(results)` and check the response

Comment: also consider that you have web developer tools in every Browser today, and you can inspect the result from the Network there.

Comment: I agree with @Aditya, just use console.log! When I threw your code snippet into jsFiddle it worked perfectly and will allow you to look through the nested structure that you're talking about.

Comment: That call is one that I have been able to get to work.Sorry I'm new to web development. I do see an error in the console: XMLHttpRequest cannot load ----- No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'null' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: Do you have a local web server running? It sounds like you are opening the file with "file://". Since you are doing CORS, you have to access your source code from a web server.

Comment: I am accessing just like the facebook call above except that it is http rather than https.